# How can I search for a place amongst my visited places in the Google Maps Android app?

Tags: google-maps, search, history, google-location-history

How can I search for a place amongst my visited places in the Google Maps Android app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any method to manually search your visited places in the native Google Maps application; the best I've been able to find is by opening Timeline and navigating by date, which isn't very helpful if you don't already know the date of your visit in advanced.  Instead, I would use a browser and navigate to your Google account's [activity controls](https://myactivity.google.com/activitycontrols/webandapp) page, and filter by Maps; this will allow you to directly search your maps visited places.